# Why is my svelte js router link component breaking routing in my demo SPA project when trying to use a slot?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

Iam new to Svelte, and JS in general. Iam building a demo dashboard project to get a grasp on Svelte after going through the framework documentation. For this, Iam not using any router for this project, just some sample code I took from a medium post to build a simple and minimal router using the svelte store.

In my App, I have 2 page components: **Home.svelte** and **About.svelte**.

I have a **router.js** file like this:

```
import Home from '@pages/Home.svelte';
import About from '@pages/About.svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const router = {
  '/': Home,
  '/home': Home,
  '/about': About
}

export default router;
export const curRoute = writable('/home');
```

In my **App.svelte**, I have :

```
<script>
 import router, { curRoute } from "@router/router";

 onMount(() => {
    curRoute.set(window.location.pathname);
    if (!history.state) {
      window.history.replaceState(
        { path: window.location.pathname },
        "",
        window.location.href
      );
    }

  });
</script>

<svelte:component this={router[$curRoute]} />
```

I have a text link component, that works fine when a use it:

```
<script>
  import { curRoute } from "@router/router";
  export let page = {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home"
  };
  function redirectTo(event) {
    // change current router path
    curRoute.set(event.target.pathname);
    // push the path into web browser history API
    window.history.pushState(
      { path: page.path },
      "",
      window.location.origin + page.path
    );
  }
</script>

<style>
  a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
</style>

<a href={page.path} on:click|preventDefault={redirectTo}>{page.name}</a>
```

At some point, I need the same component, but able to wrap some additional markup, like a card, or any other element. That's where I thought I would use the **svelte slots** feature. Therefore, I built a second component very similar to the one above, but with a slot, instead of the **{page.name}** variable. The component is like this:

```
<script>
  import { curRoute } from "@router/router";
  export let page = {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home"
  };
  function redirectTo(event) {
    // change current router path
    curRoute.set(event.target.pathname);
    // push the path into web browser history API
    window.history.pushState(
      { path: page.path },
      "",
      window.location.origin + page.path
    );
  }
</script>

<style>
  a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
</style>

<a href={page.path} on:click|preventDefault={redirectTo}>
    <slot>{page.name}</slot>
</a>
```

the **{page.name}** variable is supposed to be used as a default value when no slot content is provided. Iam able to import and use the component. Here are the two components side by side.

```
<RouterLink page={{path: '/about', name: 'About'}} />
```

```
<RouterLinkSlot page={{path: '/about', name: 'About'}}>
  <span>A nice slotted link</span>
</RouterLinkSlot>
```

But when I click on the rendered link on the frontend, it doesn't throw any error, but doesn't load the related page component and the page area remains blank, whereas it works with the non slot version. Tried to search for an answer but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old but the issue is in `event.target.pathname`.  That's only available when the click target is an `<a>` tag.  When you add a `<span>` tag, via the slot, that value became `undefined`.  Instead you should just refer to the `page.path` value that you've exported.

```js
curRoute.set(page.path);
```

You won't need event in this case.